# Chocolatey - Install major version of package and update to latest minor version

Tags: version, chocolatey

For my project, I need .NET Core 2.2. The Chocolatey package repository [states](https://chocolatey.org/packages/dotnetcore/2.2.8) that .NET Core 2.2.8 is the most recent version of .NET Core 2.2 available. I can install this package with `choco install dotnetcore --version 2.2.8 -m`. But when 2.2.9 will be released, I will still be on 2.2.8, because I specified that specific version. What command do I need to have .NET Core 2.2 updated to a new minor version when I issue `choco upgrade all`?

EDIT: I do not want to upgrade to .NET Core 3.x when I issue `choco upgrade all`, because I have some projects that depend on it. Instead, I explicitly want Chocolatey to upgrade to .NET Core 2.2.9 if it will be released

Answer (score 0):

While I think this belongs better on [Super User](https://superuser.com), based on what is implied by using side by side installations of a package, if you want a new version of that package, use `choco install -m` to install the newer version of that package. Based on your experience of `choco upgrade all` upgrading one of your side by side packages however, you may want to inquire on the [Chocolatey issue tracker](https://github.com/chocolatey/choco/issues) as to what the recommended method of upgrading your other packages would be here.

Comment: `choco upgrade all` just updates my .NET Core version to 3.0 for some reason, even if I choose the -m flag. I will look up why this weekend; this question doesn't have the highest priority for me now, but I would like to have the answer clear for me and for anybody else who might have the same question.